# Why do Disk Utility and Finder show differing available?

Tags: macos

I have a partition from which I deleted a lot of data (40GB), then emptied Trash.
Disk Utility shows 42GB available (which is pretty much what it was before the deletion).
Finder shows 110 GB available.

NOTE I have rebooted several times and checked the partition in Disk Utility.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post screenshots of what it says?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Time Machine, it could be taken up by [local snapshots](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4878) in `/Volumes/MobileBackups/`. They are not counted as used disk space in Finder, but are in Disk Utility and the About This Mac window. The snapshots should get deleted automatically if you run low enough on disk space, so they shouldn't really reduce the available disk space. But if you want to disable them, you can run `sudo tmutil disablelocal`. The setting gets reset to the default when Time Machine is turned off and back on.

Finder and Disk Utility both told that my [MacBook Air had about 25GB more used space than what all files added up to](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44877/why-do-i-have-gigabytes-of-disk-space-shown-as-hidden-space-in-daisydisk). When I tried verifying the startup disk, Disk Utility showed an error about an invalid block count, and the space was freed up after I repaired the disk.

Comment: The About This Mac window showed 68GB Backups - equal to the "missing"amount. I hadn't even known this info existed - very helpful.